# CSS centering div with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I have a parent with a fixed width

```
.parent {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
}
```

I'm trying to center a child inside of it that has a dynamic width, based on the width of an image. I don't want the child div to have any background color (so just be as big as the image)

```
.child {
  background: red;
  //how to center?
}
.image-container {
    max-height: 253px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
.image-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

How can I center the div?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YjwCq/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align: center` and remove the `position: absolute` from `child` class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YjwCq/3/)

```
.parent {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
.child {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but I forgot to mention that I don't want the child element to be bigger than the image. (My Bad!)
See updated fiddle in question.

Comment: @Kamran224 Sorry, you should add `display:inline-block` on child element. See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/YjwCq/7/

Answer (score -2):

Set .child to:

`.child {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/YjwCq/4/